# OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter gives 500 given not existing client registration Id

Tags: spring-security

When calling `/oauth2/authorization/not-existed-registration`, this returns 500. Should it return 404?

What would be the suggested way to change this from 500 to 400? Or what's the reason it's 500?

source code:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/5.5.0-RC2/oauth2/oauth2-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/web/OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java#L225

```
try {
            OAuth2AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest = this.authorizationRequestResolver.resolve(request);
            if (authorizationRequest != null) {
                this.sendRedirectForAuthorization(request, response, authorizationRequest);
                return;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            this.unsuccessfulRedirectForAuthorization(request, response, ex);
            return;
        }
```

```
private void unsuccessfulRedirectForAuthorization(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Exception ex) throws IOException {
        this.logger.error(LogMessage.format("Authorization Request failed: %s", ex, ex));
        response.sendError(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value(),
                HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.getReasonPhrase());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our case we type `registrationId` freely so I still decide to make it return 400, coz API user complains my API when seeing 500 and the API user will not complain when seeing 400 and try to figure out themselves.

Here is my solution if someone encounters the same issue.

```
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.DEFAULT_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_BASE_URI
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.DEFAULT_FILTER_PROCESSES_URI


    class MyWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter @Autowired constructor(
    ) : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

        override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
            val validator = ValidationFilter()
            http
                .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("$DEFAULT_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_BASE_URI/**", DEFAULT_FILTER_PROCESSES_URI)
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(
                    validator,
                    OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter::class.java
                )
                .oauth2Login()
        }
    }
```

Filter

```
class ValidationFilter(val registrationRepository: RegistrationRepository) : OncePerRequestFilter() {

    override fun doFilterInternal(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
        filterChain: FilterChain
    ) {

        val registrationId = request.requestURI.split("/").last()

        val findById = registrationRepository.findById(registrationId)
        if (findById.isEmpty) {
            response.sendError(
                HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value(),
                "Registration $registrationId is not configured. Please configure $registrationId before using"
            )
        } else {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quoted from [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5564) in the Spring Security repository

> As per spec, if the Authorization Request contains invalid parameters or missing parameters than the status should be 400.
> However, if an incorrect `clientRegistrationId` is sent than a status of 500 is returned. The reason for this is because at this point the Authorization Request has not been triggered by the client and the client is unable to resolve the requested `ClientRegistration` because the `clientRegistrationId` does not exist in the `ClientRegistrationRepository`. IMO this use case is likely a configuration/setup error by the user so it signals to the user to correct the configuration.

Comment: 500 should be reserved for some server side error.  This is a bad request, plain and simple.